# Swift - Close row when clicking on an action

Tags: swift

I am creating different actions when the table is in edit mode.
When the user swipes left on a cell to open the options, if the status of the cell is active, it will show the Disable button, instead will show the Enable button.

All fine.

The problem is that I want to close the cell when the user clicks on Enable or Disable buttons.

The only way to close the cell now is to click on the cell itself, instead I want to trigger this action also when the user clicks on Enable or Disable buttons, since I am not deleting the row entirely but just changing options internally.

I am trying to achieve this in this way:

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath.row], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```

But for some reasons that piece of code is crashing my app.

Any help?

Thanks

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    let builderModuleStatus = builderModules[indexPath.row].status

    let disableAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Disable", handler:{(action, indexpath) -> Void in

        self.builderModules[indexPath.row].status = "disabled"
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath.row], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    });

    let enableAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Enable", handler:{ (action, indexpath) -> Void in

        self.builderModules[indexPath.row].status = "active"
    });
    enableAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.298, green: 0.851, blue: 0.3922, alpha: 1.0);


    if(builderModuleStatus == "active"){
        return [disableAction]
    }else{
        return [enableAction]
    }
}
```

Comment: if I remember right `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` expects array of indexPath as first param

Comment: @sage444 that is not what I am doing? I give just one indexPath inside the square brackets.

Comment: I see `indexPath.row` not  `indexPath`

Comment: @sage444 Ok but how do I specify the single row then?

Comment: NSIndexPath object contains section number and row in section in other words its "pointer" of one row, so just pass whole indexPath

Answer (score 5):

To do that just add this line on your action handlers :

```
tabelView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```

Comment: This will reload the entire table and stop the editing mode. This is not what I am looking for. I need to close just the single cell, not the entire edit mode.

Comment: Just tried it and the table is not reloaded (cellForRowAtIndexPath not called) and you can still edit that table after calling this function. About the single cell I cant mange to swipe multiple cells at once because if on cell is swiped when I click the other cell, opened is closed